# SQLite3 issue with getting row ID

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sqlite

it's the first time I am using Sql database and in a quick search I have reached a video explaining how to add an external file called "2SwiftData" , it has many func such as "createTable" etc. now a few Q: 
1) am I supposed to close and open the DataBase? 
2) why cant I find the table I created in spotlight search? 
3) one of the func is `SD.lastInsertedRowId()` which should return the ID of the row yet no matter what I do, 0 is returned , and the table has info row in

The function:

```
public static func lastInsertedRowID() -> (rowID: Int, error: Int?) {

    var result = 0
    var error: Int? = nil
    let task: ()->Void = {
        if let err = SQLiteDB.sharedInstance.open() {
            error = err
            return
        }
        result = SQLiteDB.sharedInstance.lastInsertedRowID()
        SQLiteDB.sharedInstance.close()
    }
    putOnThread(task)
    return (result, error)

}
```

The request:

```
    let ra = SD.lastInsertedRowID() <br>
    print(ra)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The
`SD.lastInsertedRowID()`
returns last inserted rowid in current  session.
By doing 
`SQLiteDB.sharedInstance.open()`
 you have started new connection session in which you had no INSERT's. The [manual](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) says that in this case lastInsertedRowID should return 0. And there is what you got.